# xcode pod install

Tags: swift, xcode, pod

Имею такой podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

#use_frameworks!
target 'app' do

    pod 'ApiAI/Core'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'OneSignal', '2.5.0'
    pod 'Realm'
    pod 'SinchRTC'
    pod 'SinchVerification'

    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
    pod 'NYTPhotoViewer', '1.2.0'
    pod 'ProgressHUD'
    #pod 'RCAudioPlayer'
    #pod 'RCMessageKit'
    pod 'RCSinchService'
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'RNCryptor-objc'
    pod 'SoundManager'
  pod 'ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl'

  pod "DownPicker"

end
```

Проблема в том, что без строки `use_frameworks!` дате ошибку, что не может найти модуль `DownPicker`, а если строку раскомментировать, то идут ошибки в других модулях

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 0):

До выхода `Xcode 9 beta 4` и `CocoaPods 1.5.0`, **Swift** не использовал статические библиотеки (это что касается `use_frameworks!`) Но так-как статика стала доступна совсем недавно, не все библиотеки еще перешли на этот подход. Поэтому для вас будет решением, либо сменить библиотеку, либо использовать `use_frameworks!`

Comment: проблема в том, что, если использую `use_frameworks!`, то появляются другие проблемы с другими библиотеками. Проблему решил так : не использовал `use_frameworks!`, создал bridging-header.h, добавил туда иморт этой библиотеки (`DownPicker`), убрал со всех свифт файлов `import DownPicker `, теперь ошибки нет и саму библиотеку `DownPicker` могу использовать (без иморта, сразу в коде ее объявляю)

Comment: Напишите тогда пожалуйста ваш ответ в списке ответов, для других пользователей. У которых может возникнуть эта проблема.